# Getting count of rows with data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, mysql-8.0

I was wondering if we can get the count of number of rows based on a certain condition in Mysql along with the limited dataset rather than querying the data query and count query seperately.
Eg.

```
select * 
from table1 order by id limit 10;

select count(1) 
from table1;
```

So I stumbled upon this.

```
select count(1) over() as record_count, t1.* 
from table1 as t1 order by id limit 10;
```

This gives the exact same results as the previous two queries combined.

Two questions:

1. Is using count over() faster/better compared to running two queries? if yes then why, if no then why.
2. If the answer to above question is yes, how can I write the count over() query using HQL language (I dont want to use native query due to @OneToMany association).

Thank you!

Comment: 1) test it a you will know

Comment: Have you checked that HQL does not have window functions?

Comment: The first 2 queries could be combined eg select * ,(select count(*) from table1)
from table1 order by id limit 10;